# Angular CLI routing node_modules

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular-cli

I'm currently getting my feet wet in angular4 with the angular cli environment, and I'm trying to import the bootstrap.css from my modules in a way that feels right.

I'm currently importing it from my app.component.css like so:

```
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

This works, but having a relative path to a folder that should really be hidden doesn't sit well with me.

In the past I've used node to get around this by using an express static route:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use('/scripts', express.static('node_modules'));
```

But since angular CLI seems to cut node out of the development process, I'm looking for an alternative way to do that.

I tried adding to my module.ts:

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
        { path: 'scripts', redirectTo: './node_modules', pathMatch: 'full' }
    ])
]
```

But this dosn't seem to be doing anything. I'm not sure if I'm referencing my paths incorrectly, or I'm misusing the router module all together.

Is there a better way to bring in 3rd part assets?

Comment: You dont need a router to import third party css or js in Angular

Comment: The router is more about avoiding using a path to node_modules

Answer (score 1):

Angular CLI will compress all CSS code into a couple of files after the build. You don't have to expose `bootstrap.min.css` though angular routes for it to work.

Rather, [you can include it in configuration file](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-include-bootstrap).

Comment: Thanks, I figured there was something like this.
But I still have to point it to my node_modules folder?

I guess I could just make a path variable...